# Is there ever a reason to use scp instead of rsync?

Tags: ssh, rsync, scp

Is there a reason to use `scp` instead of `rsync`? I can see no reason for using `scp` ever again, `rsync` does everything that `scp` does, with more safety (can preserve symlinks etc).

Comment: Short answer: No. scp is *never* harmful.

Comment: @Shadur scp is harmful in that it overwrites existing target files by default. So's rsync, but it at least allows limiting the possible damage with `-u`.

Comment: @Gilles As with any tool, you must understand what it does and how it does it to use it safely.

Comment: In that context, regular `cp` and `rm` would be considered "harmful" -- and if you define "harmful" as "can screw me over if I do something stupid", `rsync` isn't any less harmful.

Comment: `scp -a` will not work, and will be slower. I see no reason to use it, if you have something else at hand. rsync is less harmfull in the sense that it can at least preserve symlinks, so can cp.

Comment: The other combination that I sometimes use, mostly with lots of small files, is `ssh user@source "cd /source/dir; tar -cf - stuff i want to send" | { cd /dest/dir; tar -xf -; }`. (Sometimes adding a gzip (mostly -1, I tend to do it over LAN connections) to the pipeline, depending on the data). It mainly handles large amount of small files better than most methods, if you have a reliable connection.

Comment: On systems without `rsync` installed, using `rsync` is (obviously) not even possible.

Answer (score 58):

scp provides a cp like method to copy files from one machine to a remote machine over a secure SSH connection.

rsync allows you to syncronise remote folders.

They are different programs and both have their uses. scp is always secure, whereas rsync must travel over SSH to be secure.

Comment: Also, pretty sure rsync has to be installed on the other end.

Comment: @ckhan, no it can copy without having anything installed in the other side, it'll just be less efficient.

Comment: @Alex so the answer is: "scp ensures that you will always encrypt the data on the wire, rsync doesn't" (the fact that rsync has more features doesn't mean it can't be used as a mere cp)

Comment: I like scp's simplicity.

Comment: @mikebloch How do you do that? Is it a new feature? Just tried this using version 3.0.9. and it complained it couldn't find `rsync` on the remote.

Comment: @mikebloch, it has to be installed on the server to do the checksum computations, which can add a lot of cpu load to the server.  This is why most large sites don't support it, and why `zsync` was created as an alternative.

Comment: @AlexChamberlain why is scp simpler than rsync? (and the point that you have to have rsync on server is a valid point).

Comment: `scp` will run over SSH just as `rsync` does. In fact, the only thing `scp` on the client side does is it runs `scp` with `-f`/`-t` flags on the remote via SSH `exec_command` channel, and writes / reads the stream that is provided as stdin / stdout. So the third paragraph of this answer does not contribute anything here.

Answer (score 26):

One of the main things (which I think no one mentioned) is that if you are transferring large amounts of data or files, and if the transfer is disconnected before completion for any reason, rsync will pick it up where it left off. Whereas scp doesn't.

I use scp if I want to transfer one or couple of files or directories. I go to rsync for multi GB size data.

Comment: Might be worth adding that the `--partial` flag is useful when transferring large files.  `rsync` will pick up where it left off within the file rather than starting that file again.

Comment: As @Flup mentioned rsync won't leave anyt file-in-transit around for you to resume unless you use the --partial option. These files are by default hidden in the target directory. You can use --partial-dir to put all of these files in a single directory.

Comment: Well, `rsync -vP username@host:/path/to/file .` will do this too. See this **[answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20244585/how-does-scp-differ-from-rsync/21476688#21476688)** on **Stackoverflow**

Answer (score 14):

**rsync**: Transfers **deltas**(using its [Delta Transfer Algorithm](https://rsync.samba.org/tech_report/)) between:

1. **local** and **remote** hosts

**scp**: Transfers **whole files** between:

1. **local** and **remote** hosts
2. **remote** and **remote** hosts

Summary: `scp` can transfer files between two remote hosts while `rsync` doesn't support it.

Comment: rsync can transfer files between two remote hosts. In fact, `rsync a host:b` is equivalent to `scp a host:b`.

Comment: That's what I wrote, rsync can transfer deltas between local and remote hosts but scp is not limited to just that, it can transfer deltas between two remote hosts. @brandizzi

Answer (score 2):

[User Chris at Webhosting Talk](//www.webhostingtalk.com/showthread.php?t=1085577#post_message_7707374) writes:

> `rsync` compares the files at each end and transfers only the changed
>   parts of changed files. When you transfer files the first timeo it
>   behaves pretty much like `scp`, but for a second transfer, where most
>   files are unchanged, it will push a lot less data than `scp`. It's also
>   a convenient way to restart failed transfers - you just reissue the
>   same command and it will pick up where it left off the time before,
>   whereas `scp` will start again from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

`scp` is simpler to use as it takes less arguments. I catch myselv using scp instead of `rsync` if I only transfer a single file. Propably I am just to lazy to define an alias to rsync... ;-)

Comment: Hmmm, why is it so? `rsync a host:b` is equivalent to `scp a host:b`, same number of arguments.

Comment: @mikebloch Two letters more to type... ;-) In the past I had to supply "-e ssh -a" to get the proper result. Now that "-e ssh" is default this might be a different game.

Answer (score 1):

Credits to @tomrunia at https://gist.github.com/KartikTalwar/4393116

```
rsync -aHAXxv --numeric-ids --delete --progress \
  -e "ssh -T -c aes128-gcm@openssh.com -o Compression=no -x" \
  [source_directory] user@hostname:[target_directory]/
```

Pay attention to `--delete`, don't use it if you want to keep extraneous files in dest dirs